# Is it possible to create database structure from F# code

Tags: f#

I am using SQL Provider to work with Access/SQL Server databases:  insert and retrieve data.

I am just wondering if it is possible to create database structure (tables and indexes) usign F# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework Code First seems like what you're looking for. Here are a few articles about doing that with F#:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/F-Code-First-Development-326dede1

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/04/04/f-code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4-1.aspx